# Power Apps - Microsoft Flow Send Emails to multiple users

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have the following table in my backend,

Table1

```
Name      ID      ToAddress                                                        Status
Abc       123     asdfg@example.com,koldef@example.com,asdasdasfda@example.com        A        
Def       234     nanasd@example.com,asdfg@example.com                                A
Ghi       567     asdfg@example.com,asdasfg1@example.com                              B
```

And I have a button in my power apps to send email, but not Sure how to write code to do this.

I want to send emails to everyone in the To address corresponding to status "A",

On the To Address there will always be only one user. And Each user will receive only one email.

The email sent to asdfg@example.com will be something like this in the body.

Please kindly take a look at
Abc - 123
Def - 234

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create two nested `Apply to each` actions:

- first for each row in Table1 with `Condition` inside: `[Status] is equal to 'A'`
- second inside `If yes` part of above condition

Before the 2nd loop create e-mail array (array type variable) by splitting `ToAddress` column *(of currently processed Table1 row)* on comma with `split()` function:

```
array(split(outputs('email_string'),','))
```

Inside the 2nd loop put `Send an email` action with dynamic content:

```
items('Apply_to_each_email_address')
```

in `To` field. Populate other necessary fields with row content - `concat()` function could be helpful.

---

Do not forget to somehow mark each row as "processed" in case of workflow failure.

Simplified version of this workflow below (only second `Apply to each` action).

[image: ]]

Comment: Can i send the just one final email to all the recipient in one go? instead of for each loop for one by one.

Comment: Yes. Create new variable of type `String` and append e-mail addresses to it separated by comma. Then use `array()` function with `split()` on comma like in my answer above in order to create an array.
Finally, use it in "To" field of `Send an email` action